# default value for CascadeType in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate to persist this bean.

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    private Address addr;
}
```

What is the `CascadeType` for `addr`?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

CascadeType *defaults to the empty array* . See [CascadeType in Annotation Type OneToOne](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html#cascade%28%29)

> By default no operations are cascaded.

Comment: Does it work for the JPA, i'm hoping it is the same.

Comment: JPA is the specification. Hibernate is an implementation of this specification, just as e.g. EclipseLink. So, yes. If it is in the documentation of the spec, it should be the same for all implementations.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle this is not always the case. The default values may vary. Example the manyToOne and the oneToOne annotation in JPA have an eager default fetching mode while in hibernate it is a lazy fetching mode.

Comment: @ihebiheb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601032/default-fetch-type-for-one-to-one-many-to-one-and-one-to-many-in-hibernate/42168093#42168093. But yes you still might want to check the implementation documentation to see if no spec defaults where overridden. Even though that is, after all, bad practice in my opinion.

Answer (score 28):

You can check the source of `@OneToOne` at [here](http://kickjava.com/src/javax/persistence/OneToOne.java.htm) . No operations are cascaded  by default

```
  /**
     * (Optional) The operations that must be cascaded to
      * the target of the association.
     *
     * <p> By default no operations are cascaded.
     */
   CascadeType[] cascade() default {};
```

Read more: http://kickjava.com/src/javax/persistence/OneToOne.java.htm#ixzz1d6ZWMM2y