# Hibernate deletes parent from a ManyToOne relation?

Tags: java, hibernate, cascading-deletes

If you are working a lot with CascadeType.ALL it is easy to get to the following design:

```
@Entity
public class Group {
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Person {
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  Group group;
  ...
}
```

Which tells Hibernate to delete the whole group if one person of that group is to be deleted... 
If the group has other persons, this fails because of foreign key constraints "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails".

I use now:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH})
```

Is there a shorter solution?

Comment: The shorter an better solution is to not have (manually) `cascade` setting at all. Let it be the default, they are chosen by the experts to be what they should be.

Comment: The default would be no cascading at all, according to [ManyToOne.cascade](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html#cascade()) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048268/default-value-for-cascadetype-in-hibernate)