# How to use OpenSessionInViewInterceptor?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, lazy-initialization

Consider entity

```
public class User {
...
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<SocialCredential> credentialsList = new ArrayList<SocialCredential>  ();
}
```

with DAO Implementation method

```
@Transactional
@Override
  public User getUser(long id){
  Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  User u = (User) s.get(User.class, id);
  return u;
}
```

and Controller

```
@Controller
      public class DummyController {
       @Autowired
       UserDAO userDAO;

       public void anyMethodAccessedByGetORPost(){
         User u= userDAO.getUser(1L);
       }
      }
```

A simple query for entity User automatically fires query to initialize entity list of SocialCredential ? Ultimately it leads to LazyInitializationException.I came to know to know about OpenSessionInViewInterceptor which can solve the issue.How can I apply the same. I am already following http://www.jroller.com/kbaum/entry/orm_lazy_initialization_with_dao but with no success so far.

Answer (score -1):

A simple query for entity User automatically fires query to initialize entity list of SocialCredential ?

> > It depends on underlying persistence API's default fetch type. 
> >     [Refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601032/default-fetch-type-for-one-to-one-many-to-one-one-to-many-in-hibernate)

Ultimately it leads to LazyInitializationException -- This is probably you are trying access `credentialsList` collection after session has been closed.

Replace DAO's `getUser(Long id)` method with below code may solve `LazyInitializationException`.

```
@Transactional
@Override
public User getUser(long id){
   Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   User u = (User) s.get(User.class, id);
   if (u != null) {
      u.getCredentialsList(); //it loads the SocialCredentials before session closes.
   }
   return u;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but that's not the answer of my question .Its a hack to eargerly load the detached entities which can be easily done using FetchType.EAGER.As my question states I am interested in implementing OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.