# Hibernate Mapping Annotation default-lazy False

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hbm file like this

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
<class name="com.pack.parent" table="Parent">
```

I am not able to find how to annotate the `default-lazy`, should I do with `@Proxy`. Please suggest me.

Comment: Well it's always `lazy` by default in hibernate, you can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/26601720/3669624 .

Comment: I know how to do for manytoone, onetomany, manytomany and onetoone. But this default-lazy is mentioned at directly in the mapping.